# Jogo usando palavras no Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Estou tentando fazer um jogo no Pygame que consiste em ir destruindo as palavras de acordo com as teclas digitadas. Ainda estou no início e estou tendo dificuldades em fazer o jogo inserir randomicamente as palavras em tela, mas sem apagar as anteriores ou sem sobrescrever.
Eu gostaria que aparecesse a palavra na tela e, após um intervalo de tempo (2 segundos, por exemplo), outra palavra aparecesse e assim por diante, todas sendo iniciando em posições aleatórias no eixo x e indo da direção do topo à borda inferior. Essas palavras estão em uma lista predefinida por mim. Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar.

```
import random
import pygame, sys, os
from random import randint

pygame.init()

# Janela
SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 600
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

# Cores
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
PINK = (234, 212, 252)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GRAY = (200, 200, 200)

# Fontes
DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()
FONT = DIRECTORY + "/fonts/unispace_rg.ttf"

pygame.display.set_caption("Shooting Words")

list_words = ["cachorro", "planta", "arvore"]

def render_text(index):
    #text = random.choice(list_words)
    text = list_words[index]
    font = pygame.font.Font(FONT, 24)
    text_render = font.render(text, True, PINK)

    return text_render

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pos_y = 0

running = True

while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pos_x = randint(0, 150)
    index = randint(0, len(list_words)-1)
    SCREEN.blit(render_text(index), (pos_x, pos_y))
    pos_y += 1

    pygame.display.flip()
    SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fiz uma classe para ficar mais fácil de gerenciar cada 'palavra' na tela.

```
class Palavra:
    def __init__(self, text: str, pos_x, pos_y=pos_y):
        self.text = text
        self.x = pos_x
        self.y = pos_y
        self.text_render = FONT.render(self.text, True, PINK)

    def draw(self):
        self.y += VELOCIDA_QUEDA
        SCREEN.blit(self.text_render, (self.x, self.y))

    def remove_letra(self, keydown):
        tecla = pygame.key.name(keydown)
        if tecla not in self.text.lower():
            return

        i = self.text.index(tecla)
        _text = list(self.text)
        del _text[i]
        self.text = "".join(_text)
        self.text_render = FONT.render(self.text, True, PINK)
```

No método `remove_letra` da classe `Palavra` é onde vai remover cada letra da 'palavra' de acordo com as teclas pressionadas. Já no método `draw`, é responsavel por escrever a 'palavra' na tela e incrementar a posição `y` com `VELOCIDA_QUEDA`.

Para gerar novas posições no eixo `x` fiz da seguinte forma:

```
LARGURA_MAX = 150
def nova_posicao_x():
    pos_x = randint(0, LARGURA_MAX)

    while pos_x in pos_xs:
        pos_x = randint(0, LARGURA_MAX)

    pos_xs.append(pos_x)
    return pos_x
```

Sempre que gerar uma nova posicão `x` para uma nova 'palavra', vai verificar se outra 'palavra' na tela já tem a mesma posição. Se não, salva numa lista e retorna a nova posição `x`.

Para escrever novas palavras na tela usei duas metricas, o tempo e uma distância minima entre cada palavra (`ALT_MIN_ENTRE_PALAVRAS`), pois se deixar apenas no tempo pode acabar gerando uma palavra por cima da outra, caso trave durante a execução ou algo assim. E além disso, para ter controle melhor das palavras, podendo aumentar a dificuldade alterando os valores de `ALT_MIN_ENTRE_PALAVRAS`, `TEXT_DELAY` e/ou `VELOCIDA_QUEDA`.

```
ALT_MIN_ENTRE_PALAVRAS = 100
def nova_palavra(ticks):
    global TEXT_NEXT_TIME

    if palavras:
        if (palavras[-1].y >= ALT_MIN_ENTRE_PALAVRAS) and (ticks > TEXT_NEXT_TIME):
            TEXT_NEXT_TIME = ticks + TEXT_DELAY
        else:
            return
    ...
```

Considerei que somente a primeira 'palavra' da lista vai ter a letra removida se pressionar alguma tecla, a 'palavra' é removida da lista se passar do limite da tela ou se todas as suas letras forem removidas.

```
def remove_letra(event_keydown):
    index = 0
    palavras[index].remove_letra(event_keydown)
    if not palavras[index].text:
        remove_palavra(index)
```

```
ALT_MAX_PARA_REMOVER = HEIGHT - 5
def remove_palavra_fora_da_tela():
    for i, palavra in enumerate(palavras):
        if palavra.y > ALT_MAX_PARA_REMOVER:
            remove_palavra(i)
```

Coloquei no [github](https://github.com/ffernandoalves/ShootingWords) o código completo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Fernando. Encontrei uma solução parecida com a sua. Ainda vou fazer várias melhorias, mas segue o link do github:

[github](https://github.com/fabiovsn/Space-Words/blob/main/main.py)